# how to chain script command

Tags: bash

Im trying to create an alias that captures my terminal using script when im updating my packages.

```bsh
scripttime() {
    script --timing=${1-typescript}.time ${1-typescript}.log
}
alias update-n-log='scripttime ~/log/test/test.$(date +%d-%m-%YT%H-%M-%S); update_me'
```

This only runs the update_me command after the script recording is done. Can i automate script capture in an alias? I tried to google for it but the name script makes it hard to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  `script -c update_me` seems to be what you are looking for, at the core.  And it also seems like the alias is superfluous -- It can just be a single function:

```
update-n-log() {
  FILENAME_BASE="~/log/test/test.$(date +%d-%m-%YT%H-%M-%S)-typescript"
  script -c update_me --timing=${FILENAME_BASE}.time ${FILENAME_BASE}.log
}
```

P.S. Freebie Google tip -- Searching for "script terminal recording" (without the quotes) came up with some better hits, but I agree -- It's a rough name to search for.

Also don't forget to `man script`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. altho i had to change the tilda '~' to $HOME for that to work, seems like ~ would not translate into its path in a string and script would not accept that path, i also changed update me to "UPDATE_COMMAND" and defined it in the function for better readability, just my style.